# Using a variable to output MySQL column value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$tag = 6;   
$user_checkn = db_query("SELECT ".$tag." FROM advent_user_check WHERE uid=".$_SESSION ['uid']." LIMIT 1");  
$user_check = mysql_fetch_array($user_checkn);
echo $user_check[$tag];
```

This outputs 6 instead of the db value which is 0. Why?

**UPDATE**

Figured it out: the backticks around the column name were missing:

```
$user_checkn = db_query("SELECT `".$tag."` FROM advent_user_check WHERE uid=".$_SESSION ['uid']." LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: You must enter field name instead of $tag.

Answer (score 1):

$tag isn't the name in the database. In your code, $tag is 6, so it prints that. What is the column name? You are basically saying `SELECT 6 FROM advent_user_check WHERE uid=....`

Comment: $tag is the name of the column ( for example 6 )